# Writing back to Config file Powershell

Tags: powershell, configuration-files

I have a config file which I want to replace/change certain lines within using PowerShell.

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($a -join "`r`n"))
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($b -join "`r`n"))
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
```

I am trying to write back to the config file with the changed data within the variables, $a, $b and $c. (So three lines in the config file which I want changing). However, this isn't working and only changed the line $c.

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($a -join $b -join $c -join"`r`n"))
```

I have tried this, however, the output is wrong. 
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Why are you using `[IO.File]::WriteAllText` instead of something more common like `Out-File`?

Comment: I am learning and so following on from another example. This is what they used.

Comment: Just a tip:
If don't need to, don't use the .Net commands instead of the normal powershell commandlets. If you're still learning, read through https://4sysops.com/archives/writing-to-files-with-powershell-redirect-tee-out-file-set-content/ . This should explain most of the stuff pretty good.

Comment: "The output is wrong" ... *how*? Please show samples of input and desired as well as actual output.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will take a look!

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers. I considered doing that, however the config file I am working with has around 100 lines in it and so would make the post huge. Plus, just an example of myself trying out different things.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at Out-file as recommended by Paxz, success!

```
$a | out-file $_.FullName
```

This code has replaced the previous three lines of code.

I had to change my variables so that they are each $a (instead of $a, $b, $c). This updates $a each time with -replace, then writes $a to the file with out-file.